# What verb or phrase do you use to say that something wants someone to do something for them, but they don't say it directly?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What verb or phrase do you use to say that something wants someone to do something for them, but they don't say it directly and if the person did that think for her or him, they make the person believe that it was the person who wanted to help them?

Comment: [*If you want someone else to completely believe in your idea, you must make them believe that it was their own idea all along. And one of the most strategic ways of doing this is to first **plant a seed into the person's head**.*](https://www.businessinsider.com/heres-how-you-trick-people-into-thinking-your-idea-is-their-own-2013-1?r=US&IR=T) But "making them believe it was their own idea" is a very specialized type of [psychological] manipulation - I seriously doubt there's any particularly "standard" expression for it.

Comment: Let's say a girl wants a guy to ask her out. What phrase would you use to say that she managed to get the guy ask her out without showing her interest in the guy?

Comment: Manipulative? Sly?

Comment: Can I say "the girl cunningly got the guy to ask her out"?

Comment: It can be possible to [**manoeuvre**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/manoeuvre) someone: 2.1 Manipulate a situation to achieve an end. (**maneuver** in AmE).

Comment: She **inveigled** him into asking her out maybe? It's kind of sneaky.

Comment: [*cajole coax convince lure persuade tempt wheedle beguile ensnare entice seduce talk bamboozle blandish con dupe flatter fool soft-soap sweet-talk sucker bait butter butter up charm deceive decoy entrap honey hook induce influence jolly manoeuvreUK maneuverUS manipulate massage oil snow soap stroke toll trick urge egg on get around lead on overdo it rope in soften up string along sweet talk...*](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/inveigle.html) There are lots of "relevant" words, but I don't think English has a *specific* word/phrase for the requested sense, so it's POB.

Comment: on an unrelated note, may I ask what POB stands for?

Comment: Possibly "[to allude](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/allude?s=t)" -- to refer casually or indirectly; make an allusion. And also "[to imply](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/imply?s=t)" -- to indicate or suggest without being explicitly stated.